# What are 0xaa and 0x55 doing?

Tags: java, python, operators, bit-manipulation

I tried Googling, but couldn't find anything comprehensible @.@ ...
Could someone please explain in layman's terms what is happening in this code?

It's a problem from the book "Cracking the Coding Interview".

"Write a program to swap odd and even bits in an integer with as few instructions as possible (e.g., bit 0 and bit 1 are swapped, bit 2 and 3 are swapped, and so on)."

The way I did it didn't involve bit manipulation because I couldn't figure out how %\ ...

```
def swap(n):

    b = bin(n)[2:]
    print(b)
    if len(b)%2 != 0:
        c = True
        b = b[0] + b

    pairs = wrap(b, 2)
    pairs = [i[::-1] for i in pairs]
    ans = ''.join(pairs)

    if c: ans = ans[1:]
    print(ans)
```

But now I'm looking at their answer and I don't really get it... (doesn't help that it's not in Python) :

```
int swapOddEvenBits(int x) {
  return ( ((x & 0xaaaaaaaa) >>> 1) | ((x & 0x55555555) << 1) );
```

Comment: They're masks, to mask either the odd or the even bits. They're then shifted, both at the same time, odds one to the right and evens one to the left, to swap them.

Comment: First half - `&` your `int` with `101010...` - this means odd bits stay the same, even bits are `0`; sign insensitive shift the whole lot up one bit. Second half - `&` your `int` with `010101...` - this means even bits stay the same, odd bits are zero; sign sensitive shift the whole lot down one bit. You how have all the right pieces in the right places - `|` them together. It would help you to break down the code and print out the binary at each step.

Comment: So the question isn't really about [tag:python] or [tag:java]...

Comment: You can use python to view the binary equivalent of those values:  `bin(0xaaaaaaaa)` gives you `'0b10101010101010101010101010101010'` and `bin(0x55555555)`  gives you `'0b1010101010101010101010101010101'`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, oooooooh, so for something like x = 110100, shifted odd bits look like 010000, and shifted even bits are 101000, and then | gives 111000. Whoa. That's cool :) Learn something new every day.

Comment: is it a typo that one is ">>>" and the other is "<<" ? should they both have three?

Comment: @Raksha nope, that's correct. The difference is related to twos-complement representation of numbers.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, you wouldn't happen to have a quick reference to that on hand, would you?

Comment: Could try [Oracle's tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's break this down.

```
return ( ((x & 0xaaaaaaaa) >>> 1) | ((x & 0x55555555) << 1) );
```

First, we'll look at `(x & 0xaaaaaaaa)`. If you break `0xaaaaaaaa` down to the bit level, you end up with `1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010` (as `a`, in binary, is `1010`). So `(x & 0xaaaaaaaa)` is saying, return only every even-placed `1` in `x`. This is called bit masking. Then, you right shift it by one place - this is how you make the even numbers switch place (so now the second bit occupies the place of the first bit, and the fourth the third, etc).

You do the same thing with `(x & 0x55555555)` - if you break it down to the bit level, you end up with `0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101` (as `5`, in binary, is `0101`). This masks all the even-placed bits in `x`, and gives you all the odd-placed bits. Then, you shift all bits left by 1. Finally, you use the `or` (`|`) operator to combine the two bit-sequences, and that's your answer.

Example:
Let's take 2456086205. We convert that into binary and get `1001 0010 0110 0100 1110 0110 1011 1101`. Now, we do `(x & 0xaaaaaaaa)`, and get

`1001 0010 0110 0100 1110 0110 1011 1101 & 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010`,

which equals `1000 0010 0010 0000 1010 0010 1010 1000`. Shift this to the right and you get `0100 0001 0001 0000 0101 0001 0101 0100`.

Now, do `(x & 0x55555555)`, and get

`1001 0010 0110 0100 1110 0110 1011 1101 & 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101`,

which equals `0001 0000 0100 0100 0100 0100 0001 0101`. Shift this to the left and you get `0010 0000 1000 1000 1000 1000 0010 1010`.

Finally, we do `0100 0001 0001 0000 0101 0001 0101 0100 | 0010 0000 1000 1000 1000 1000 0010 1010`. We then get `0110 0001 1001 1000 1101 1001 0111 1110`, which, as you can see, is the the solution!

Comment: why is 'a' 1010 in binary? I'm getting 01100001.

Comment: 01100001 is the _character_ code for a (as a letter) converted to binary, but 0xa is 10, in hexadecimal. 10 = 2 + 0 + 8 + 0, so it's represented as 1010 in binary.

Comment: oh %\ ... damm, now there's hexadecimals too X.x ... never used those before. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Raksha It's a bit confusing at first, but it's definitely something good to know. Our number system = base 10, binary = base 2, and hexadecimal = base 16! Here's a helpful tutorial: https://betterexplained.com/articles/numbers-and-bases/

Comment: Thank. I'll definitely have to read up on that. i just find it strange that python can just & them together like that without having to convert one to be the same type as the other >.> ....

Comment: @Raksha that's just the thing - under the hood they are the same type! 0xaaaaaaaa is a number written in base 16; 2456086205 is a number written in base 10; but internally all numbers are represented in binary (as that's how computers store data). So really, it's just two different ways of you telling the computer (in base 10 and base 16) to store a (base 2) number.

Comment: hmmmmmm ... is there no logical right shift in Python? Well that kinda ruins the whole code :I ... Gotta add that 0 manually.

Answer (score 7):

Converting to binary,

```
0xaaaaaaaa == 0b10101010101010101010101010101010
0x55555555 == 0b01010101010101010101010101010101
```

These numbers have 0s and 1s set in alternating locations, so when you `&` a number with one of these, it picks out every second bit.

If you perform the swapOddEvenBits procedure with an integer, let's say `0b01111100111101001111110000110010`, we get

```
0xaaaaaaaa & 0b01111100111101001111110000110010 selects the following bits:
               0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1     # unselected bits are 0

0x55555555 & 0b01111100111101001111110000110010 selects the following bits:
                1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0

0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 gets shifted right:
 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1

and
 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 gets shifted left:
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0

and we | the results back together:
 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
-------------------------------
10111100111110001111110000110001
```

Answer (score 1):

We know that 0xaa and 0x55 are hexa-decimal representation .
Moreover each character in hexadecimal is represent using 4bits

so , 0xaa is equivalent to 1010 1010 (since, a = 1010 in binary)
and 0x55 is equivalent to 0101 0101 (since, 5 = 0101 in binary)

Anding any number with them return us alternative bits of the
number and thus useful while solving problems like swapping odd 
and even digits.